# Competitive Programing: Factorial Time limit exceeded

Tags: java

I am working on a very simple spoj problem in which we have to take input N calculate its factorial then find out number of trailing zeros and display it some thing like

Sample Input:

6

3

60  // fact of 60 has 14 trailing zeros

100

1024

23456

8735373

Sample Output:

0

14

24

253

5861

2183837

so i have written a code which is working fine on my machine but when i am submitting it is giving me time limit error. i don't know how to make this code fast. So i want suggestions from you guys.

```
public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int t = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                Long num = Long.parseLong(bf.readLine());
                BigInteger bd = BigInteger.valueOf(num);

                System.out.println(countTrailinZeros(factorial(bd.toString())));
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            return;
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger factorial(String n) {
        BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for (long i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(n); i++) {
            x = x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static int countTrailinZeros(BigInteger bd) {
        String s = bd.toString();
        int glen = s.length();
        s = s.replaceAll("[0.]*$", "");
        int llen = s.length();

        return glen - llen;
    }

}
```

I have googled about some possible solutions and found out that lookup table may work i don't have much idea about this. I'd be very thankful if some can explain me about lookup table.

edit: Could it be java is too slow to solve this problem in given time? or in general it is not favorable to use java for competitive programing?

Comment: If all you need to do is to print out the number of trailing 0's, why calculate the factorial at all?

Comment: no but in the given problem it has written that we have to calculate no. of trailing zeros of the factorial of input number.

Comment: There is a way to determine the number of trailing zeros in a factorial without calculating the factorial itself.

Comment: @DavidConrad and what is it? can you explain me?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to look at the first N factorial numbers and look for a pattern in when trailing zeros appear, but every trailing zero represents a factor of ten in the number, right? And the prime factorization of ten is...? And which prime factors of ten are going to be more common, and which are going to be the limiting factor...?

Comment: ok i got it i need to work on 2 and 5. thank you

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to calculate factorial to get number of trailing zeroes.

Solution :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int lines = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int sum, N, p;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            sum = 0;
            p = 5;
            while (N / p != 0) {
                sum = sum + N / p;
                p = p * 5;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Logic is :

The highest power of a prime number `p` in `N!` is given by

```
floor(N/p) + floor(N/p*p) + floor(N/p*p*p) ... so on till [floor(N/p^n) = 0]
```

so since number of ending zeroes is required , `ans = min(max power of 2 in N!, max power of 5 in N!)`
because zeroes appears on multiplication by ten and ten can be decomposed to `10 = (2 * 5)`.

It is fine to assume that max power of 5 in N! is always less than max power of 2 in N!.
as multiples of 2 occur more frequently than multiples of 5.

So problem reduces to finding `max power of 5 in N!` and hence the solution.

Example :

```
N = 5
max power of 5 in 5! = floor(5/5) + floor(5/25) => 1 + 0 => ans = 1

N = 100
max power of 5 in 100! = floor(100/5) + floor(100/25) + floor(100/125) => 20 + 4 + 0 => ans = 24
```

Comment: I am not getting part inside while loop. It is working fine but how is it working as we are concerned about min factors of 2 and 5 for eg fact of 5 is 120 it contains 1 factor of "5" and 3 of "2". so the ans would be 1. I got this part but i didn't get how you make it work in code.

Comment: @NitinJaiman Updated with example. You only need to worry about N here and not N!

Comment: @NitinJaiman first `p = 5` , then `p = p * 5` hence `p = 25`. Next `p = 25 * 5` so `p = 125` , then `p = 125 * 5` so `p = 625` so on

Comment: @sujithvm Thank You so much. I got it this time. kudos

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem in spoj platform, you just have to divide the value by 5 until the value becomes less than 5. print all the result of the division and that's your output.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, consider prime factorization of N factorial:

> N! = 2^a1 * 3^a2 * 5^a3 * .... where a1, a2, a3, ... >= 0

Since N! = N*(N-1)*(N-2)*..., multiples of 2 are more frequent than 5.

So, a1 >= a3 in this expansion.

Number of trailing zeros = how many times you can divide N! by 10.

Which implies, ans = min(a1, a3) based on the prime factorization given above.
Since we already proved a1 >= a3, hence ans =  a3, i.e power of 5 in the prime factorization of N!.

- There will be floor(N/5) numbers that will contribute to power of 5 atleast once.
- There will be floor(N/25) numbers that will contribute to power of 5 atleast twice.
- There will be floor(N/125) numbers that will contribute atleast thrice

and so on.

The total power of 5 = floor(N/5) + floor(N/25) + floor(N/125) + ...

Implementation of this formula in code is left as an exercise.